# Python data types

Tags: python, types

Is this statement true?

> Python does not enforce a strict type
>   on containers or variables. With this
>   concept, developers can design a
>   container to hold different types of
>   data

I'm doing an essay on Python and found this statement on a [random site](http://ugweb.cs.ualberta.ca/~c410/F07/410/presentations/ReportPython.pdf), just wondering if anyone could clarify it for me, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this list

```
mixed = [ "hello", 3.1415926, 42, (1+2j) ]
```

The list has 4 items, each of a different type.

In Java, you have to declare a type.

```
List<String> javaList= new LinkedList<String>();
```

This Java list can only hold String objects.

Comment: technically, you could declare a `List` as `List<Object> javaList = new LinkedList<Object>();`. You can throw anything into that list, as long as it isn't a primitive. Insofar, non-typeenforcing containers are not a feature that differentiates Python from Java.

Comment: @piquadrat - difference is that if you havean Object List in Java, you can only perform Object operations (member function or as argument) with those list elements.  In the python list `mixed` S. Lott shows you could iterate on mixed[0] for the string, or get the real/imag part of mixed[2]

Comment: @jon_darkstar: "you can only perform Object operations" or you are forced to engage in the type-mangling "cast" operation.  Something Python folks don't have and don't need.

Answer (score 10):

Yep its true.

Besides designing a container, regular lists can hold several types

```
>>> myList = [1, 3.14, 'string', {'key1':'value1'}, frozenset([5,2,2,3]), [1,2,3],(5+2j),(4.0,5.0), True, type(5)]
>>> myList
[1, 3.1400000000000001, 'string', {'key1': 'value1'}, frozenset([2, 3, 5]), [1, 2, 3], (5+2j), (4.0, 5.0), True, <type 'int'>]
>>> [type(x) for x in myList]
[<type 'int'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'frozenset'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'complex'>, <type 'tuple'>, <type 'bool'>, <type 'type'>]
```

Even `type` is a type

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers note, this is certainly true of python. I would also like to point out that this is a feature of several high-level languages including Ruby and even JavaScript (iirc). As far as Java goes it is technically possible to design a container that will hold
multiple types but it requires those types to be derived from the same type, and then the types must be cast to be used as usual. For example in Java one could write:

```
Object[] mObjArr = new Object[2];
String mString = "This is a String";
Double mDouble = 3.1415;

void assignElements() {
   mObject[0] = (Object) mString;
   mObject[1] = (Double) mDouble;
}
String getString() {
   if (mObject[0] instanceof String) return (String) mObject[0];
   else return null; // or empty string or throw exception etc.
}
Double getDouble() {
   if (mObject[1] instanceof Double) return (Double) mObjects[1];
   else return null; // or Double.NaN or throw exception etc.
}
```

A similar solution in C/C++ using pointers to void is possible
but type checking becomes hairy to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

In Python everything is an object:

```
>>> id("hello world")
4312841696
```

Here, you can see how even a literal (an string in this case) has a memory space reserved for it.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
...
>>> id(Foo)
4297723600
```

Even the Classes are instances of an object. So, considering this, a list/dict/set just contains references to objects, no matter instances of what classes they are.

```
>>> a = [40L, "test", Foo, Foo()]
>>> a[0]
40L
>>> a[1]
'test'
>>> a[2]
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> a[3]
<__main__.Foo object at 0x1010e8710>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Standard containers are untyped: you can store any value in a list or mapping, and use almost any value as a key in a mapping. Java has untyped containers, too, but usually people enforce static type checking by using generics.
2. You can implement interface of a container (not explicitly, you just define a set of methods with right names) and your class will work as a container. You may do what you please, including type checking, having default values, efficient storage, etc.
3. Lists (arrays) in Python have rich subscript semantics, e.g. you can get one- and multi-dimensional slices using simple expressions. Both built-in and third-party special containers (e.g. from `numpy`) use it to great effect.